# problems while ploting two line using geom_line

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this:

[image]

```
df<-structure(list(Date = c(141, 111, 71, 153, 57, 8, 83, 83, 111, 
99, 99, 43, 43, 22, 15, 22, -7, 153, 15, 29, 71, 29, 57, -7, 
127, 141, 127, 8), Result = c(173, 156, 154, 131, 154, 126, 171, 
114, 132, 133, 177, 188, 135, 179, 177, 152, 171, 185, 117, 117, 
174, 193, 161, 119, 175, 116, 121, 175), Test = c("Math", "Math", 
"ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "Math", "ELA", "ELA", "ELA", "Math", 
"Math", "ELA", "Math", "Math", "ELA", "Math", "Math", "ELA", 
"ELA", "Math", "Math", "Math", "ELA", "Math", "ELA", "ELA", "Math"
)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I would like to plot it, x=date, y=result, color=test. This should be a very easy task but I keep getting error message. Where did I make mistake? Any suggestion to better plot those info?

My codes are:

```
ggplot(data =df)+ geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Result, color = Test, yaxs="d", xaxs="d"),size=0.8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_line` connects observations, ordered by x value and is part of `ggplot2` package.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = Date, y = Result, color = Test)) +
  geom_line(size=0.8) +
  xlab("d") + ylab("d")
```

[image]

Comment: why can't I use `yaxs="d", xaxs="d"` in my codes?

Comment: you can use `xlab("d") + ylab("d")`. Please see my edit of the code above. Many thanks.